# what could be causing this rails ioerror closed stream?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, ioerror

I have a rails application, running in development mode ( with a sqlite database ). The application's purpose is to allow users to upload files through a java client.

If a user wants to upload a folder, all the files inside it will be recursively uploaded. If a user wants to upload a file, the file will be uploaded normally.

Here's the error I'm receiving :

```
 IOError

    in UploadedFilesController#new

closed stream
```

Here is the application trace :

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/tempfile.rb:167:in `close'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/tempfile.rb:167:in `callback'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/vendor/builder-2.1.2/blankslate.rb:85:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/vendor/builder-2.1.2/blankslate.rb:85:in `method_added'
app/controllers/uploaded_files_controller.rb:114
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `load_file'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `new_constants_in'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:202:in `load_file'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:94:in `require_or_load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `load_missing_constant'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:453:in `const_missing'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:465:in `const_missing'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:257:in `constantize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:148:in `constantize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/routing.rb:1426:in `recognize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/webrick_server.rb:78:in `service'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/commands/servers/webrick.rb:66
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:496:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `new_constants_in'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:496:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/commands/server.rb:39
```

Here is the framework trace :

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/tempfile.rb:167:in `close'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/tempfile.rb:167:in `callback'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/vendor/builder-2.1.2/blankslate.rb:85:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/vendor/builder-2.1.2/blankslate.rb:85:in `method_added'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:170:in `handle_request'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:115:in `dispatch'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:126:in `dispatch_cgi'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:9:in `dispatch'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/webrick_server.rb:112:in `handle_dispatch'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/webrick_server.rb:62:in `dispatch'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3
```

Here is the full trace :

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/tempfile.rb:167:in `close'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/tempfile.rb:167:in `callback'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/vendor/builder-2.1.2/blankslate.rb:85:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/vendor/builder-2.1.2/blankslate.rb:85:in `method_added'
app/controllers/uploaded_files_controller.rb:114
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `load_file'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `new_constants_in'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:202:in `load_file'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:94:in `require_or_load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `load_missing_constant'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:453:in `const_missing'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:465:in `const_missing'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:257:in `constantize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:148:in `constantize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/routing.rb:1426:in `recognize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:170:in `handle_request'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:115:in `dispatch'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:126:in `dispatch_cgi'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:9:in `dispatch'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/webrick_server.rb:112:in `handle_dispatch'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/webrick_server.rb:78:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/webrick_server.rb:62:in `dispatch'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/commands/servers/webrick.rb:66
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:496:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `new_constants_in'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:496:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/commands/server.rb:39
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3
```

I have no clue why this happens ... the client gets to upload about 15-30 files ( from a folder, through the java client ) before this error appears. I am running Rails 2.0.2 . Could the fact that I'm running in development mode using sqlite as a database cause this ? Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks guys !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've figured it out, at least I think I do ( the client just keeps on uploading now, error-free ) . 
After you read data from a file that you upload, you should also **CLOSE** it. Who would have thought? :P

Comment: I'd agree, but do you know why that matters? Are you running out of space in some way?

Comment: @JosephHolsten Good question! I would like to know the same!

Answer (score 2):

We ran into this same problem with our Rails application, although simply closing the file object didn't work for us (we use Paperclip, and it does close the File).  I developed a monkeypatch to the Tempfile class that has fixed it for us, and we use as a Rails initializer.

You can grab it from http://github.com/jwinky/ruby_tempfile_ioerror

Comment: I have the same issue. Used the monkey patch from above, but that didn't help. Any other ideas?